# Is it possible to port an X11 server to the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, x11

I'm looking for an X11 server on the iPhone to be able to use the [NX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NX_technology) protocol. There are RDP clients, Citrix clients, VNC clients, but no X11 server...

Do you think it is possible to port (or create ?) an X11 server (by example [kdrive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kdrive) modified for Cocoa) for the iPhone? Does it have enough CPU-power or memory for that? How would you do that? Are there alternatives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you should take a look at [Zingersoft](http://www.zinger-soft.com/support_a_4.html). Your second step will probably be working to get [XQuartz](http://xquartz.macosforge.org/trac/wiki) compiling for iPhone.

Comment: Thank you for the iX11 app at Zingersoft, it is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Removed from app store :(

Answer (score 4):

It certainly has enough CPU power and memory - X11 has been running on < 10mhz machines since it's inception.  Of course, these didn't support blending, anti-aliasing, shape extensions, etc.  Clocking in at 600mhz+ and a modern graphics chip, the iPhone is a smoking monster machine.

Zingersoft though provides, as Rob Napier said, an X server, so obviously must be possible :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible. Whether it makes sense or not is a different matter - X is not only the drawing protocol, it's the interaction model as well. You'd be hard-pushed to do right-clicks, control-characters or most other operations that X programs will want to do.

Frankly, you're probably better off hosting a VNC session onto a remote X session held by a run of the mill Linux box rather than going down this road if all you want to get is bits on the screen.